# How to use timeit with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, timeit

I am trying to learn how to use timeit with Numpy. I am getting stuck in the basics while using Python 3.

````
import timeit

data = np.genfromtxt('data/example_data.csv',delimiter=';', names=True, dtype=None, encoding = 'UTF')

print(timeit.Timer(max([row[3] for row in data]))))```


Error that I am getting:

C:\Users\LucasBatistadosSanto\Documents\handsondata\ch_02>python pan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pan.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(timeit.Timer(max([row[3] for row in data])))
  File "C:\Users\LucasBatistadosSanto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\timeit.py", line 128, in __init__
    raise ValueError("stmt is neither a string nor callable")
ValueError: stmt is neither a string nor callable
````

Comment: You probably want `t = timeit.timeit(lambda: max([row[3] for row in data]), number=1)`